# Issue in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed **wordpress on Amazon cloud** and and added a post in in my wordpress website but it is not showing me that post on my website, instead it is showing

*"It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet. "* 
All this content is in my **index.html** file which is located in **/var/www**
I used this tutorial to install my wordpress
http://iampuneet.com/wordpress-amazon-ec2/

Kindly assist

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Remove index.html (or rename it to index.old)

Comment: hi David, i have the similar issue..i have installed rails in AWS Ec2 and always showing "It works .." message. Do you want me to rename the index.html file in AWS box ?